# Run function on button click as the creator user - Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I want to trigger a function when the user (Even with view only permissions) clicks a button that will run as the creator's user.
For example:
I create a spreadsheet that shows a list of stuff, the list might be updated from time to time but I don't want the time driven function or onOpen to drain my total run-time quota.
So I want to create a button that runs a function as my user so when I share the link of the program with someone that can not edit the list he would still be able to refresh it.

I think installable triggers run as the trigger's creator user so the solution might be there but I couldn't find it.
Thanks for any help given,
Gur.

Comment: Sounds like what you want to achieve can be done with [Custom Menus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus?hl=en). Have you looked into that approach?

Comment: I thought about it but it won't be located inside the spreadsheet. I need the button to be located inside the sheet, in fact, I have few buttons and all of them are located in different strategic.
If the system I am working on was supposed to be for myself I wouldn't mind but since it supposed to be intuitive I do have to make it in-cell.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a Google Drawing and assigning a script to it.

From you spreadsheet select Insert -> Drawing, then create your Drawing. You can then place this Drawing anywhere on the sheet. So that may help since you want the buttons to be in strategic locations.

Once that is done use the drop down box on the Drawing and select "Assign Script..." and type in the name of your function.

Same premise as Custom Menus but you aren't restricted to their location.

Comment: That is what I did by now but I do need to make the script to run as my account. How do I do that?

Comment: Typically you need to deploy a script as a web app to allow the script to be accessed by other users but only run as you. It is one of the options for you when you go to setup the web app. I suggest starting there and seeing if that works for you. These options can all be found within the script file you are working with.

Comment: Now, how do I assign my script to the image that is inside the sheet? I tried as always to assign the script "submit" when the add on is in test mode but it says that the script can not be found.
Is there an easy was to do this? like creating a trigger that recognizes the click on the image?

Comment: @GurTelem I believe you use the same method as Bender405 answered previously.  Also you should mark Bender405's "Answer" to your original question as complete.

Comment: When I deploy the script as web app it won't be connected to the sheet so I need to deploy it as add on but then when I assign the script I want to the image it says that the script could not be found. My original question is hot do I assign a script to a button that will run always as me. I still need an answer and therefore I won't yet mark my question as complete.